Geometry Nodes: Color Variation Based on Z-Coordinate Not Working As Intended
I'm attempting to define a float value for a face dependent on its location on the z-axis (image 1). I have set up a shader to visualize the float value (image 2). I would expect the value determined from the separated z-axis to be the same for all faces with the same z-height- however this is not the case. The values radiate out from the center of the grid instead of forming parallel lines. How can I fix this?



i don't see anywhere in your node tree where you are setting the z-value to your position? if it is set in the mesh, just use "position -> separate -> z into store named attribute" - no more and it will work

@Chris Thanks. It seems that normalizing interfered with the separate z output. Map range has sorted it.

Removing the Normalize node and mapping to range has made the values store properly.
Taking minimum and maximum face positions allows this to be applied to geometry of any size.


Side note: The Attribute Statistic node could be set of type Float to work only on component Z instead of the whole Position vector, saving a bit of time and two Separate XYZ nodes.

@StefLAncien That produces a strange result- the faces where z=1 are shifted downwards (by 2.2, it appears)- the faces are blue from halfway up/down.
